# Calling call by reference c program in Python program using Ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am tried to call c swap function in python program. Using shared object method, but i am stuck to pass address of python variable address.

i am new to python language and used Python version is 2.7.

### C program :

```
void swap_addr(int *num1, int *num2) {
int temp = *num1;
*num1 = *num2;
*num2 * temp;
}
```

### python program :

```
from ctypes import *

val1 = 10 ;
var2 = 20 ;

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./swaplib.so');
lib.swap_addr.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p] ;

Addr_Var1 = POINTER(c_int);
Addr_Var2 = POINTER(c_int);

print ("Before swap val1 and var2 is " + str(var1) + " & " + str(var2))

lib.swap_addr( Addr_Var1(c_int(var1)), Addr_Var2(c_int(var2)) )

print ("After swap val1 and var2 is " + str(var1) + " & " + str(var2))
```

i expect the output as :
Before swap val1 and var2 is 10 & 20
after swap val1 and var2 is 20 & 10

but actual output is coming as :
Before swap val1 and var2 is 10 & 20
After swap val1 and var2 is 10 & 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `c_int(val1)`, you're creating a new `c_int` object. This object contains the C-style integer variable. You can get a pointer to it easily using [`byref`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.byref) for function calls. Python's `int` type, on the other hand, is not mutable and may not be modified, even if you do find the address to it; thus `val1` and `var2` cannot be swapped. So your sample should look more like:

```
from ctypes import *

var1 = c_int(10)
var2 = c_int(20)

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./swaplib.so')
lib.swap_addr.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p]

print ("Before swap var1 and var2 is " + str(var1.value) + " & " + str(var2.value))

lib.swap_addr( byref(var1), byref(var2) )

print ("After swap var1 and var2 is " + str(var1.value) + " & " + str(var2.value))
```

Incidentally, `POINTER` produces a pointer type, which is precisely the same in both your `Addr_Var1` and `Addr_Var2`. It's not until you created values of the type they pointed to different places, in the arguments to `swap_addr`, and they were immediately discarded (quite possibly in the wrong order).

Comment: Thanks yann for quick support, After change to _byref_ in python program, i am getting Error message as **AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'byref'**

Comment: That's not the only change - in fact, it's the less important one. Look at each place `var1` or `var2` is mentioned.

Comment: Once again thanks for your support. now its working as i expected.